# Is there a way to wrap arbitary commands located under a subdirctory in a shell script

Tags: zsh

I have a bunch of customizations and would like to run my test program in a pristine environment.
Sure I could use a tiny shell script to wrap and pass of arguments but it would be cool and useful if I could invoke a pre and possibly post script only to commands located under certain sub directories. The shell I'm using is zsh.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you include in your “pristine environment”.

If you want to isolate yourself from the whole system, then maybe [chroot](https://serverfault.com/questions/267227/why-is-chroot-never-used-on-mac-os-x/267285#267285) is what you're after. You can set up a complete new system, with its own `/etc`, `/bin` and so on, but sharing the kernel, networking and other non-filesystem stuff with your running system. Root's cooperation is required (the `chroot` system call is reserved to root).

If you want to isolate yourself from your dot files, run the program with a different value for the `HOME` environment variable:

```
HOME=~/test-environment /path/to/test-program
HOME=~/test-environment zsh
```

If this is specifically about zsh's configuration files, you can set the `ZDOTDIR` environment variable before starting it to tell zsh to run its own dot files from a directory other than `$HOME` (or `zsh --no-rcs` to not load any dot file).

Answer (score 0):

If by *pristine environment* you mean a fully controlled set of environment variables, then the `env` program does this.

```
env -i PATH=$PATH HOME=$HOME program args
```

will run `program args` with **only** the environment variables you specified.